# {message":"Failed to discover OP endpoint URL"} - passport-paypal in nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, paypal, passport.js

My application is in nodejs, and im integrating for Paypal authentication using passport-paypal

**Middleware code**

```
const PPStrategy = require('passport-paypal').Strategy;

passport.use(
            new PayPalStrategy(
                {
                    clientID: 'My Paypal clientID',
                    clientSecret: 'My PayPal secret Id',
                    returnURL: 'localhost:4000/paypal/callback',
                    scope: 'openid'
                },
                function(identifier, done, next) {
                    return next(null, identifier);
                }
            )
        );


ppRouter.get('/paypal', passport.authenticate('paypal'));

ppRouter.get(
    '/paypal/callback',
    passport.authenticate('paypal', { failureRedirect: '/Home' }),
    function(req, res) {
        //My logic on successful authentication
        res.redirect('/Home/Payments');
    }
);
```

The above implementation gives me the error

> {"message":"Failed to discover OP endpoint URL"}

I have tried to pass **callbackUrl** instead of **returnUrl** URL in the strategy but i get the same issue.